# For move assignment, will memory leak occur if destruction is left to the rvalue?

Tags: c++11, rvalue-reference

With reference to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293665.aspx) , at the end (Section: Robust Programming) it states,

> To prevent resource leaks, always free
>   resources (such as memory, file
>   handles, and sockets) in the move
>   assignment operator.

What will happen if the move assignment is instead implemented as:

```
MemoryBlock& operator=(MemoryBlock&& other)
{
   if (this != &other)
   {
      std::swap(_data, other._data);
      std::swap(_length, other._length);
   }
   return *this;
}
```

Wouldn't the "_data" of the rvalue that "other" references be freed when it goes out of scope?

Comment: It will be freed if the destructor of `MemoryBlock` frees it.

Comment: Yes the destructor in the example frees it. I am just curious about the statement in the MSDN article because swapping members seems to be a simpler way to write the move constructor and move assignment methods. But swapping will not free the memory within the move assignment.

Comment: You're in fact very close to the simple method of the [copy-and-swap idiom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom). (Note, you only need to write *one* assignment operator, not two, done right.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `other._data` will be freed when it goes out of scope (assuming a good destructor of course).  However there is one item to consider:  If `other._data` refers to a resource that needs a *timely* destruction, it may be destructed *late* in this design.  An example might be the locked state of a mutex.